# How to delete duplicate document with one different value

Tags: mongodb

I want to delete the duplicate records where one field SourceSystem is different and can have 3 acceptable outcomes. I am unsure of how to continue from this point forward

```
db.claims.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {claimNbr: "$claimNbr"},
  dupes: { "$push": "$claimNbr" },
  count: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$match: { count: {"$gt": 1}}}],
   {allowDiskUse: true})  

.forEach(function(doc) {
     doc.dupes.shift();
     db.claims.remove({ "claimNbr": {"$in": doc.dupes }});
     db.claims.createIndex({"claimNbr":1,},{unique:true})
       print(doc._id.claimNbr)
     }
});
```

If the value in SourceSystem is different than expected then the record that doesnt match needs to be deleted.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample docs !!

Comment: By definition, duplicates must have the same value. If you have two documents with different values, they're not duplicates. Please post the two example documents, and point out which one should be deleted.